# Angular 10 and igloo authentication

Tags: angular

I am implementing igloo authentication in angular 10 application, spend a whole day but unable to find the way how to do it.

Below is the code provided by the firm to implement this in angular app

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.io_global_object_name = "IGLOO";

window.IGLOO = window.IGLOO || {
  "enable_flash": false,
  "bb_callback": function (bb, complete) {
    console.log(bb, 'bbbb')
  },
  "loader": {
    "version": "2",
    "subkey": "1234"
  }
};

(function () {
  var tv = document.createElement('script');
  tv.type = 'text/javascript';
  tv.async = true;
  tv.src = 'https://loader.min.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(tv, s);
})();
</script>
```

I just need to get the value of bb in one of my component which is not the first route or the initially loaded page. Used many different methods but unable to get it done.

Ex: If I put this in index.html then how will I execute `bb_callback` function in particular component. Someone help me overcome this problem and I am open to any other opinion as well. Thanks in advance and please ask for more clarification if needed.